# Calculating distance between two points using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I have 4 coordinates on map.

```
lat1 = radians(47.434756)
lon1 = radians(42.971468)
lat2 = radians(47.542419)
lon2 = radians(42.946061)
```

I want calculate distance between this.

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
R = 6373.0

lat1 = radians(47.434756)
lon1 = radians(42.971468)
lat2 = radians(47.542419)
lon2 = radians(42.946061)

dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1

a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

distance = R * c/100

print("Result:", distance)
```

My code say that distance is `0.1212`.
ArcGIS says `0,11062` (shape length).

But when I measured with a ruler - its shows 9.23km.

How do I correctly calculate distance with ArcPy?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to use spherical haversine computation when ArcPy already has the full Inverse (aka Reverse) [Problem of Geodesy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems) implemented via the Esri Projection Engine.

The key here is to use the [arcpy.PointGeometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm) type (`arcpy.Point` is a simple helper class to store double precision values), with *an explicit* `SpatialReference` *parameter*, set to your preferred geographic coordinate system. This example uses WGS84:

```py
import arcpy

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)               # WGS84
sr.setFalseOriginAndUnits(-400,-400,10000000)   # ten millionth of a degree ~= 1.1112 cm resolution

p1 = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(42.971468,47.434756),sr)  # always use spatial_reference!
p2 = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(42.946061,47.542419),sr)
a1,d1 = p1.angleAndDistanceTo(p2,'GEODESIC')
a2,d2 = p2.angleAndDistanceTo(p1,'GEODESIC')

print("Distance = {:8.3f} meters, Bearing1->2 = {:9.5f} degrees".format(d1,a1))
print("Distance = {:8.3f} meters, Bearing2->1 = {:9.5f} degrees".format(d2,a2))
```

The results are in degrees and meters (unless the SpatialReference is projected, in which case it's in the units of the projection):

```
Distance = 12122.175 meters, Bearing1->2 =  -9.07843 degrees
Distance = 12122.175 meters, Bearing2->1 = 170.90285 degrees
```

Note that, even for such close points, the angle of 2->1 is not a full complement of the angle from 1->2, since the path follows the curvature of the Earth.

---

If the lat and lon are flipped from the values you provided (`Point` takes x,y parameters, which is lon,lat)...

```py
p3 = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(47.434756,42.971468),sr)
p4 = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(47.542419,42.946061),sr)
a3,d3 = p3.angleAndDistanceTo(p4,'GEODESIC')
a4,d4 = p4.angleAndDistanceTo(p3,'GEODESIC')

print("Distance = {:8.3f} meters, Bearing3->4 = {:9.5f} degrees".format(d3,a3))
print("Distance = {:8.3f} meters, Bearing4->3 = {:9.5f} degrees".format(d4,a4))
```

then the distance is 9.23 kilometers.

```
Distance = 9227.107 meters, Bearing3->4 = 107.77524 degrees
Distance = 9227.107 meters, Bearing4->3 = -72.15139 degrees
```